# Why does my cross-compiling fail?

Tags: c, gtk, cross-compiling, mingw32

I'm new to Linux programming and I'm trying to compile a c file including the GTK+ library. My file is called `test.c` and it's supposed to run on Windows computers. I'm using the command:

```
i586-mingw32msvc-gcc `pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0` -o test test.c `pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0`
```

I get an awful error, I tried to figure out what went wrong by myself but didn't manage to understand what's going on here.

This is the output: [image: compiler output]

Comment: Please try to always upload error messages as text and not images. Also, it looks like the `pkg-config` adds the `-pthread` flag which is not known by your cross compiler.

Comment: You're trying to cross-compile a Windows binary using libraries from your Linux system. You'd have to use library flags for Windows libs for this to work.

Comment: You should set probably set the `PKG_CONFIG_SYSROOT_DIR` environment variable to let `pkg-config` know where to look for the windows-compiled librairies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're almost certainly running `pkg-config` with the host metadata files, such output will likely make your cross-compiler, erm, cross.

Try this tutorial, it explains how to do what you want starting with downloading the required GTK+-3.0  win32 binaries, and setting up your linux environment so that `pkg-config` picks up the target metadata files:

http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45

The job of [`pkg-config`](http://people.freedesktop.org/~dbn/pkg-config-guide.html) is to provide a straightforward way for one program to determine the compiler and  linker requirements, and any dependent libraries for a library it uses. It also makes it easier for `autoconf` (and the user) to determine the presence, version and dependencies of specific packages. Your examples are using:

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
pkg-config --libs gtk+-3.0
```

Those will output the compiler and library flags that a program using gtk+-3.0 needs. Assuming you have a native version installed on your system, the default output will be suitable only for your type of system (paths, library names, dependent libraries etc).

The trick with cross-compiling is to have a separate tree of source, .pc (pkg-config meta-data), libraries and header files (for each targeted architecture). When you run `pkg-config` during configure/compile, you can set `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` as in the tutorial above so it picks up the correct `.pc` files for the targeted architecture.

There's a little bear trap here though: `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` *adds* to the start of the search path, so it can still fall back to the wrong package details if you have not installed the required software into your target tree, but you have a "native" version installed. You should usually set `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` instead, this replaces the default path (typically `/usr/lib/pkgconfig`). That way when you cross-compile something more elaborate that uses autoconf (`configure` scripts) you (hopefully) get a sensible diagnostic about missing packages, rather than having the wheels come off mid-way through the compile.

For example, I can use this to list *just* the OpenWRT MIPS packages I have in one cross-compile tree:

```
WRTROOT=/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_r2_uClibc-0.9.32/
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=  PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=${WRTROOT}/usr/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --list-all
```

Unsetting `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` prevents it finding extra packages in my `/usr/local`, setting `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` means it won't find the native system ones.

Comment: It looks like the tarnyko.net link is no longer valid. I was able to find it through web.archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20220628223212/http://www.tarnyko.net/en/?q=node/45

Answer (score 0):

In addition to setting the `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` and `PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR` variables, it might be necessary to pass `--define-prefix` to `pkg-config`:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH= PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_eglibc-2.19/usr/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --define-prefix --cflags libmodbus
-I/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_eglibc-2.19/usr/include/modbus
```

Otherwise you get the include path on your host system:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH= PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR=/openwrt/staging_dir/target-mips_34kc_eglibc-2.19/usr/lib/pkgconfig pkg-config --cflags libmodbus
-I/usr/include/modbus
```

which *might* work, provided the host system and the cross-compile environment have the same include files installed.